# setting SQLite version on RStudio

Tags: rstudio

I am using the following platform:
Ubuntu 16.04
RStudio: 1.0
SQlite version: 3.11 and 3.14.

when I query sql version from RStudio using the following code:

```
sqldf('SELECT sqlite_version();')
```

returns version 3.11 if I query in command line the version is 3.14.

I have tried to remove version 3.11 using command line and synaptic package but still getting the same version in rstudio.

Any help

Comment: The RSQLite package used by sqldf includes a copy of SQLite in the package and does not rely on the copy you have separately installed on your system.

Comment: G, thanks, so how do I access this on the command system? or I have to work only on rstudio?

Comment: I mean, created databases in rstudio and access it on the command line:

Comment: If you create a database in an earlier versoin of sqlite I believe that in most cases it should work in a later version.  If you create a database in a later version it should work in the earlier version as long as you don't use any features in the later version that are not in the earlier version.